# Need help with incorrect operation of the HIP4082

Tags: pwm, stm32, dc-motor, h-bridge

Trying to run HIP4082 according to the Datasheet. I use 1uf, delay resistor - 10k capacitors. At a constant 12 volts on the BHI BLI and ALI pins, the motor rotates with some pulsation. But  if i give PWM in ALI pin, then chip stop working and gets very hot. What could be the problem?
 [image]

[DataSheet](https://jp.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/hip4/hip4082.pdf)

Comment: what does this mean? ...`if the ALI file of the PWM`

Comment: @jsotola oh, sorry. if i give PWM in ALI pin, then chip stop working

Comment: Why AHI and BHI are constantly high? Won't that force both of the high-side FETs to be always on? And what happens when both AHI and ALI are high, there will be extreme crowbar current having both high and low FET on at the same time without going through the load. There must be some controller actually driving AHI ALI BHI BLI correct? Keeping those inputs constant is not good for the H-bridge.

Comment: @MarkU DS have some notes about this: "BHI B High-side Input. Logic level input that controls BHO driver (Pin 16). BLI (Pin 3) high level input overrides BHI high
level input to prevent half-bridge shoot-through, see Truth Table. DIS (Pin 8) high level input overrides BHI high level
input. The pin can be driven by signal levels of 0V to 15V (no greater than VDD)."

Comment: *"Trying to run HIP4082 according to the Datasheet."*  What's a HIP4082?  What datasheet?  I don't see one here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop updated my question

Comment: You need a better deadtime design including inductive signal delays

Comment: HIP4082 is not reliable IC,
USE IR2110.